# Vite: Configure webpack-dev-server like functionality in Vite

Tags: webpack-dev-server, vite

In webpack I could do something like to this to handle some development middleware code, which includes doing some work/testing inside the app.get call.

```
devServer: {
    before: function (app, server) {
        app.get ("/", function (req, resp, next) {
            // Do some stuff
            resp.redirect ("someUrl")
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like Vite should have some kind of similar functionality, but I have not found the right docs yet to help me out.  Does anyone have an example of this for Vite?

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#configureserver

Comment: Well, that works with the PluginApi, are you implying I need to build my own plugin?  I was hoping I could just add a small bit of code into my vite.config.ts that does similar to what I have in my webpack.config.js.  I'd love to see a small example.  Only thing I've found is the https://github.com/axe-me/vite-plugin-node, which appears to be configurable, but wondered if I needed it.

Comment: Yes, from what I have found it seems you need to create plugin. But it is not [that hard](https://github.com/chaosprint/vite-plugin-cross-origin-isolation)